# ROWLEX . Net RDF website access?

Tags: rowlex

does anone know whether ROWLEX .Net RDF library is still on or not? I have tried sevral times this week to access the website but no luck. I have lost my download and wanted it again. Maybe a URL chenged or something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's been more than a few weeks.  Did you ever get a copy of this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is down due to technical and bureaucratic issues. It will come back. I expect a few more weeks.

Comment: Is there any hope to have the Rowlex download URL back? it's 7 months already.