# Where can I obtain ROWLEX?

Tags: rowlex

I've recently started working with ontologies and I'm looking at a way to load and query them in a .Net environment. I believe ROWLEX can help me do this? Out of interest I'd like to evaluate it anyway but I can't seem to locate a download for it or another way to obtain access to it.

Can anyone advise me how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ROWLEX . Net RDF website access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870876/rowlex-net-rdf-website-access)

Comment: Unfortunately, our website is still down. Seeing our progress through the bureaucracy, it will be down for while. If you send an email to admin at rowlex dot net, you can get it.